# Conditional Statements for dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe, shown below. 
[Dataframe start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRjz6.png)

I want to look at the columns D,F,M,P and return a Result column the value that appears the most in each row.

The rules I want to make sure this statement follows are: 
1) if there is a split between the rows containing 2 IG's and 2 HY's, return HY in the Result column.
2) if a column contains a NaN value, ignore it and use the other values available.

I want the resulting dataframe to look like: 
[Result_DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz6tF.png)

```
df_Start = pd.DataFrame({'P':['IG','HY','IG',np.nan,'HY'], 'M':['HY','HY','IG', np.nan,'IG'], 'F':['HY',np.nan,'HY', np.nan,'IG'],'D':['IG','IG','IG', 'HY','IG']})

df_end = pd.DataFrame({'Result':['HY','HY','IG', 'HY','IG'],'P':['IG','HY','IG',np.nan,'HY'], 'M':['HY','HY','IG', np.nan,'IG'], 'F':['HY',np.nan,'HY', np.nan,'IG'],'D':['IG','IG','IG', 'HY','IG']})




def f(x):

frequencies = pd.Series(data=[y for y in x if pd.isnull(y)==False]).value_counts()
a,b,c = 0,0,0
if 'IG' in frequencies:
    b = frequencies['IG']
if 'HY' in frequencies:
    a = frequencies['HY']
if 'PFA' in frequencies: 
    c = frequencies['PFA']
return 'PFA' if c > 0 elif
```

for i,row in new_df.iterrows():
    new_df.loc[i,'result'] = f(row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know if it works

```
def f(x):
    frequencies = pd.Series(data=[y for y in x if np.isnan(y)==False]).value_counts()

    a,b = frequencies['HY'],frequencies['IG']


    return 'HY' if a>=b else 'IG'
df['result'] = df.columns[['D','F','M','P']].apply(lambda x: f(x))
```

I am unable to figure out right now why the above approach does not work

```
def f(x):

    frequencies = pd.Series(data=[y for y in x if pd.isnull(y)==False]).value_counts()
    a,b,c = 0,0,0
    if 'IG' in frequencies:
        b = frequencies['IG']
    if 'HY' in frequencies:
        a = frequencies['HY']
    if 'PFA' in frequencies:
        c = frequencies['PFA']
    if c>=1:
        return 'PFA'
    else:
        return 'HY' if a>=b else 'IG'


for i,row in df_Start.iterrows():
    df_Start.loc[i,'result'] = f(row)
```

The new one should work.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for replying. When I try to apply the function I get an error that returns "'AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'apply'' . Any idea?

Comment: And can you clarify what 'data' in the line of frequencies should be?

Comment: It's an argument placeholder. It's not a variable

Comment: oh. is there anyway to correct the index error that is appearing?

Comment: the new error that appears is 'IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices' ...any idea? @Parijat Bhatt

Comment: thank you. do i need to apply the function in any manner or just run the block you just posted and thats all?

Comment: Just running should do. Please comment here if it works for you.

Comment: it worked!!! Thank you very much for the help!! 

I have another question for you just to build upon this if i wanted...Let's say I had a 3rd condition label 'PF', and I want to always return that value if it ever shows up (even if it only shows up once compared to IG twice and HY twice) how would i change the above code? just add a value c?

Comment: Yes adding a value c and then checking if it's frequency is more than 1 should solve it. if you like my approach, please accept the answer. Let me know if there is anything else.

Comment: I think you can upvote it or accept it. here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: how do i write the return line if i included a C value? meaning, return 'PFA' if c > 0 elif 'HY' a >=b else 'IG' ...is that correct?

Comment: if c>0: return 'PF' else: old_return_statement

Comment: can you re-edit that into the answer? a bit confused still

Comment: def f(x):

    frequencies = pd.Series(data=[y for y in x if pd.isnull(y)==False]).value_counts()
    a,b,c = 0,0,0
    if 'IG' in frequencies:
        b = frequencies['IG']
    if 'HY' in frequencies:
        a = frequencies['HY']
    if 'PFA' in frequencies: 
        c = frequencies['PFA']
    return 'PFA' if c > 0 elif 


for i,row in new_df.iterrows():
    new_df.loc[i,'result'] = f(row)

Comment: i addded what I have so far in my initial question if it helps better explain what I am asking